# Treewalker's NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT not returning text from non HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, treewalker

Does document.createTreeWalker parse only valid DOM elements ?

```
let allTextNodes = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
```

For example at : https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/olivia-ai-inc - does it not return text within tags like `field-formatter` ?

```
<field-formatter _ngcontent-sc470="" linkcolor="primary">
...
</field-formatter>
```

Comment: Your elements are valid DOM elements. Running a TreeWalker on the linked page I can see TextNodes that have <field-formatter> ancestors. When are you running your script? And how are you iterating over your walker?

Comment: Im running the script on DOMContentLoaded - `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', afterDOMLoaded);`

Comment: And are you sure these elements have been populated at that time?

Comment: I see - so it's possible that the data is loaded even after DOMContentLoaded ? In that Im going to skip modification of such elements since it may be using a framework like Angular / React insert data. This is for a Chrome extension Im working on - and its working on most pages with text data loaded on DOMContentLoaded.